# How i can retrieve php array in the following case

Tags: php

How i can access these array in the foreach loop one by one

```
Array
(
    [quantity] => 45
)
Array
(
    [quantity] => 53
)
Array
(
)
```

I have to retrieve the quantity

Comment: By using a loop. Probably a `foreach` loop. Take a look at the documentation for the details. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: You didn't put any code in question that shows the foreach loop you talk about.

Comment: Those appear to be three different unrelated arrays. What are their names?

Comment: Question is not cleared. is all arrays are in different variables?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 53
        )

)

Comment: no one can answer this

Comment: where are the expert persons

Comment: @DanishIlyas How can you say __no one can answer this__, have you read the previous comments? Have you replied to there questions?

Comment: Does `$array['quantity']` not work...!? Show your code, the little bit you do show does not contain enough information for us to help with concrete code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use code :

```
foreach($yourArray as $array) {
echo $array["quantity"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use for each

```
foreach($arrayName as $value){
    echo $value->quantity;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but these are three different arrays, You only access them in 3 different loops or to make them multi-dimensional.

Comment: More than that, they're *arrays*, not objects.